# Commerce 'Edit Order' page taking 10 seconds or more to render

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, control-panel

The individual order view in the CP is taking 10 seconds or more to be displayed, how can we avoid/debug this?

[image]

---

PS. Can ignore the errors in the log (I think) as  they are just `mmikkel\cpclearcache\{closure}    Error registering AssetBundle - Unable to find the template “_components/utilities/ClearCaches”.`

Answer (score 1):

Just some data for comparison - on our production server, an individual order comes up in a tad less than 2 seconds...(and on local dev it's much the same actually).

Are you up to date with Commerce as there was some work on this I believe: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/828 (so version 2.1.5 & above should be better).

Or perhaps you have some very expensive custom field stuff attached on your orders??